# using logical AND within IF statement to search for file ext(tilde ~)

Tags: linux, unix, shell, shell-script, bash-scripting

Please find the below script :

```
#!/bin/bash
for index in `ls -1 /appdata/frozen_files`
do
 for bucket in `find /appdata/frozen_files/$index -name "*.gpg~" | cut -d/ -f4-5`
   do
    for files in `ls /appdata/frozen_files/$bucket/rawdata | wc -l`
     do
      if [[ ` "$files" -eq 1 && "file extension = .gpg~" ` ]];
       then
        echo $bucket >> /tmp/NAS_buckets_with_less_than_2_files.txt
      fi
     done
   done
 done
```

intend : i am trying to find the file extension=.gpg~ ending with tilde(~).
file name example= journal.gz.gpg~.. 
.gpg~ files are available on /appdata/frozen_files/$bucket/rawdata | wc -l

can we create a variable that contains the extension of the file, looking at the system has something to compare it to.

"something" that can check the file extension (.gpg~)

Comment: I have tried to make sense of your question, but a lot of it still seems wrong. Please review my edits carefully and update them to make clear what you intend.

Comment: intend : i am trying to find the file with the ext=.gpg~ ending with tilde(~) file name example= journal.gz.gpg~.. .gpg~ files are available on /appdata/frozen_files/$bucket/rawdata | wc -l

Comment: Please update your question. Since I can't work out what your problem is, it is unlikely that my reformatting is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do.

This will print all directories named `rawdata` from the inside of `/appdata/frozen_files/` that contain less than two files with names ending with `.gpg~` (files in subdirectories of `rawdata` don't count):

```
find /appdata/frozen_files/ -type d -name "rawdata" -exec \
   sh -c '
      cd "$1" || exit 1
      num=$(find . ! -name . -prune -type f -name "*.gpg~" -exec printf "\n" \; | wc -l)
      [ "$num" -lt 2 ]
   ' sh {} \
\; -print
```

The procedure is:

1. The outer `find` finds all `rawdata` directories.
2. For every such directory `sh` is called; the directory is available as `"$1"` inside the provided command.
3. This shell `cd`-s to the directory and runs the inner `find`.
4. This `find` prints a newline for every `*.gpg~` file directly in the directory.
5. These newlines are counted by `wc`.
6. The result (number) is stored as `num` variable.
7. The result is tested if it's lower than `2`.
8. If the test succeeds, the outer `find` prints the directory.

Notes:

- Few solutions are there because of portability and POSIX compliance:

  - `! -name . -prune` instead of `-maxdepth 1`,
  - `-exec printf "\n" \;` instead of `-printf "\n"`.
- The variable is used so it can be reused, e.g.:

  ```
  [ \( "$num" -gt 2 \) -a \( "$num" -lt 10 \) ]
  ```
- Use `-print0` instead of `-print` if you need to parse the output in a safe way.
- Parse the output or modify the command to extract only a part of every path you get; e.g. instead of `-print` you may want to use:

  ```
  -exec sh -c 'basename "$(dirname "$1")"' sh {} \;
  ```

  to obtain the parent directory of every `rawdata` that matches the criteria.